# Android: React-native-share returning "error: failure from system" when attempting Share.open

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I am working on a React Native app that takes pictures with the camera, stores the images, and then allows the user to save the image to their photo library, or share those images through SMS, email, social media, etc.

Among other things, I am using react-native-fs (https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and react-native-share (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) to accomplish this. Everything works just fine on iOS. The problem occurs when I try to share the stored image on Android. I did some digging, and it looks like the image must be in Base64 in order to be shared on android. I am trying to convert the image to base64 in react-native-fs and then send it along to react-native-share, but when I try to share the base64 image I get the following unhelpful error:

error: Failure from system

Here is the relevant code:

```
RNFS.readFile(this.state.sourceURI, 'base64')
    .then((res) => { 

      this.setState({androidURI: res});
    })
    .then((res) => {
      const options = {
        title: 'Share',
        message: "test",
        type: "image/png",
        url: 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.state.androidURI,
    };

      Share.open(options)
        .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
        .catch((err) => {
          Alert.alert(
        'Alert',
        "Sharing Error: " + JSON.stringify(err),
        [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            style: 'cancel',
          },
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      Alert.alert(
      'Alert',
      "Error converting to base64: " + JSON.stringify(err),
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
      );
    });
```

The error is being caught at Share.open ('Sharing Error'). If anyone could give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. If you require more information from me, I would be happy to provide it.

Thanks!!

EDIT: To clarify, this.state.sourceURI contains the following string:

'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.{my app name here}/files/Test.png'

Comment: Nevermind, got it working! I had to reconfigure the filepaths.xml file. If anyone else is having trouble with this issue, let me know and I'll elaborate on what I did.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently facing the same problem. What led you to the solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue plz post whats the resolution

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP solved the issue, the full answer was missing. Nevertheless I was able to assemble a working solution by following traces OP's comment and from https://github.com/ToluThomas/react-native-share-image. For further reference in case the link goes bad, setup guide from ToluThomas:

1. Create filepaths.xml at android/app/src/main/res/xml/filepaths.xml (if it does not already exist)
2. Add below to filepaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="myexternalimages" path="Download/" />
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

3. Navigate to your app `AndroidManifest.xml` (check `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`) and add `<provider>` like below:

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.yourAppID.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my working code snippet hope it helps

```
try {
   Share.open({
      subject: 'Download App Now',
      title: 'Download App Now',
      message: "text",
      url:"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+uri,
   }, {
       // Android only:
      dialogTitle: 'Share App',
      // iOS only:
      excludedActivityTypes: []
   }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
   )
   .catch((err) => {
      err && console.log(err);
   });
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```